# I am trying to get text but i got ?(value) and unable to click. And this is a dropdown button (by default on value is selected ) in selenium

Tags: html, selenium

```
<div class="select-wrapper initialized">
  <span class="caret">▼</span>
  <input type="text" class="select-dropdown" readonly="true" 
        data-activates="select-options-56a6924e-42d9-1f78-1b82-fe2c1cbdfbdd"
        value="R3PORTS, INC">
  <select id="comp_drpdwn" class="initialized"
         data-select-id="ff6db37d-572c-bae4-7ba8-49856f516da7">
     <option value="0">Select Company</option>
     <option value="Vault Brewing Company~TI41305172">Vault Brewing Company</option>
     <option value="Vegan Picnic~TI28950835">Vegan Picnic</option>
     <option value="Yes Hospitality Group~TI09460957">Yes Hospitality Group</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

and my code is

```
List<WebElement> out = driver.findElements(
                                By.xpath("//div[@class='select-wrapper initialized']"));
for(WebElement tuo : out) {
    String test = tuo.getText();
    System.out.println(test);
}
```

Test result is pass but i got only ?(question mark). Please help me to solve my problem

Comment: do you want to get the selected value?

Comment: replace List<WebElement> out = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.select-wrapper.initialized")); to this and check.

Comment: Please clarify you want resolve the `?` char in printed console output, or you want to click on the `<span class="caret">▼</span>`  Because `▼` is a special symbol, the console output can display it as normal.

Comment: `trying to get text` but `i got ?(value)` and `unable to click`. Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Your question does not make clear idea, what you wants. Either getting text or what you wants to click ?

Comment: i am unable to click the element(Drop down button), This only my question

Comment: Hi cruisepandey,

Comment: you are recommended code is not working for me

Comment: Hi ishita , i want to click the element

Comment: @yong i want to click the button

Comment: @Saravanna, Your given HTML code not includes the dropdown options , please find out them and update in your question.

Comment: @yong    <select id="comp_drpdwn" data-select-id="ff6db37d-572c-bae4-7ba8-49856f516da7" class="initialized"><option value="0">Select Company</option><option value="Vault Brewing Company~TI41305172">Vault Brewing Company</option><option value="Vegan Picnic~TI28950835">Vegan Picnic</option><option value="Yes Hospitality Group~TI09460957">Yes Hospitality Group</option></select>

Comment: I update the HTML code in your question, please confirm the `select` is child node of `<div class="select-wrapper initialized">`

Comment: @yong yes, the select is child node of <div class="select-wrapper initialized">

Comment: Is the `<select id="comp_drpdwn" ` visible as default (before you click the ▼ )?

Comment: no yong,by default value is R3PORTS, INC. I need to change R3PORTS, INC to another one value

Answer (score 0):

Your given HTML code miss the part of options, please find out the update in your question.

```
String option2Select = "Vegan Picnic";

WebElement selectWrapper = driver.findElement(
            By.cssSelector("div.select-wrapper.initialized"));

// click on the ▼ to expand options
selectWrapper.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.caret")).click();

// click on wanted option
selectWrapper.findElement(By.xpath(".//option[text='" + option2Select + "']")).click()
```

If above code can't work, try following code:

```
String option2Select = "Vegan Picnic";
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select#comp_drpdwn"));
      .findElement(By.xpath(".//option[text='" + option2Select + "']")).click()
```

Comment: above code not working for me. error like org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

Comment: Give the full error message, i need to know which element not visible.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Select for drop down as you mentioned in your comments

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.Xpath(".//*[@id='comp_drpdwn']""));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: His dropdown is not native, but css dropdown. We can not use `Select` class which only work for native dropdown.

Comment: @prany  i am using above the code, it's displayed error like : Element should have been "select" but was "input"

Comment: @Prany updated code also displayed error like org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate option with index: 3(i am trying index value is 0 to 10)

Comment: which browser are you  using and also tell the selenium version ?

Comment: @Prany Browser : Chrome & Selenium : 3.9.0

Comment: chrome version?

Comment: this code also not working for me (code successfully run but button was not click)

Comment: Can you try actions.moveToElement(element).click(); actions.build().perform();

Comment: @Prany  this code also not working for me (code successfully run but button was not click)

Comment: 1) Is the <select id="comp_drpdwn" not visible as default (before you click the ▼ )  2) default value is R3PORTS, INC. I need to change R3PORTS, INC to another one value

Comment: Can you try with actions.moveToElement(element).click(); actions..build().perform();

Comment: what is your chrome version ? I hope it is sync with selenium 3.9 ?

Comment: Chrome Version 66.0.3359.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: @Saravanan - I hope you are also using ChromeDriver 2.39.

Comment: @Prany  yes i am using  ChromeDriver 2.39

Comment: i am not yet get solution for my problem, please any one help me to solve my problem